# Background music (MediaManager.createBackgroundMedia) causes crashes at app closing/opening

Tags: android, codenameone

I have an issue with background music playback in my app (it's a game), for some reason app crashes if you remove app from Android's recent apps list, switching to another app works fine, in other words, if I put app in background and then resume, it works, music stops and resumes (please see the code below), but if I kill the app then it crashes

As far as I know this only happens on Android 6, I have tested on LG Nexus 5 and Samsung Galaxy S7, sometimes app doesn't crash when you kill it, but does crash when you start it after

This doesn't happen on Android 8

init()

```
String fileName = getAppHomePath() + "bgmusic.mp3";
try {
    InputStream inputStream = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/bgmusic.mp3");
    OutputStream outputStream = openFileOutputStream(fileName);
    Util.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    backgroundMedia = MediaManager.createBackgroundMedia(fileName);
    backgroundMedia.setVolume(50);
    backgroundMedia.play();
} catch(IOException e) {
    Log.e(e);
}
```

start()

```
if (backgroundMedia != null) {
    if (!backgroundMedia.isPlaying()) backgroundMedia.play();
}
```

stop()

```
if (backgroundMedia != null) {
    if (backgroundMedia.isPlaying()) backgroundMedia.pause();
}
```

destroy()

```
if (backgroundMedia != null) {
    backgroundMedia.cleanup();
}
```

initially there was no code in `destroy()`, I put it there just in case it gets called at the moment app gets killed, but it keeps crashing anyway

I also got (DDMS) logs from device

```
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952): Activity com.manyukhin.cerebrate.words.synonyms.WordsSynonymsStub has leaked ServiceConnection com.codename1.impl.android.e$3@df3ed35 that was originally bound here
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.manyukhin.cerebrate.words.synonyms.WordsSynonymsStub has leaked ServiceConnection com.codename1.impl.android.e$3@df3ed35 that was originally bound here
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1092)
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:986)
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1303)
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1286)
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604)
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at com.codename1.impl.android.e.g(AndroidImplementation.java:3133)
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at com.codename1.o.q.d(Display.java:4152)
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at com.codename1.media.c.a(MediaManager.java:65)
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at com.manyukhin.cerebrate.words.synonyms.v.a(Unknown Source)
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at com.manyukhin.cerebrate.words.synonyms.WordsSynonymsStub.a(WordsSynonymsStub.java:133)
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at com.manyukhin.cerebrate.words.synonyms.WordsSynonymsStub$1.run(WordsSynonymsStub.java:114)
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at com.codename1.o.q.m(Display.java:1137)
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at com.codename1.o.q.j(Display.java:932)
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at com.codename1.o.ai.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at com.codename1.impl.b$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
11-15 14:51:42.431: E/ActivityThread(4952):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-15 14:51:42.548: E/PBSessionCacheImpl(3716): sessionId[16344683113135691] not persisted.
11-15 14:51:42.628: E/ACDB-LOADER(198): Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154): Process: com.manyukhin.cerebrate.words.synonyms, PID: 5154
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.codename1.media.AudioService@134375 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3027)
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442)
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154):     at com.codename1.media.AudioService.onStartCommand(AudioService.java:59)
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3010)
11-15 14:51:43.635: E/AndroidRuntime(5154):     ... 8 more
```

As I understood `createBackgroundMedia()` starts Service, and then doesn't stops it when app gets killed, is there any workaround for that ?

**EDIT**

issue confirmed on Android 4.3, 5.0 and 6.0

I have changed the code to the following:

start()

```
String fileName = getAppHomePath() + "bgmusic.mp3";
try {
    InputStream inputStream = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/bgmusic.mp3");
    OutputStream outputStream = openFileOutputStream(fileName);
    Util.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    backgroundMedia = MediaManager.createBackgroundMedia(fileName);
    backgroundMedia.setVolume(50);
    backgroundMedia.play();
} catch(IOException e) {
    Log.e(e);
}
```

stop()

```
if (backgroundMedia != null) {
    backgroundMedia.cleanup();
}
```

I thought that this will help, as `backgroundMedia.cleanup()` should stop playback and free-up all related resources including background service, but this didn't help, issue is still there

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question I don't think you actually need background playback. You can use the regular play method. The background play method is meant for apps that need to play when they are minimized (e.g. a music player which keeps playing when your phones screen is turned off).

Comment: @Shai, I see what you mean, that makes sense, but as I understood, to do that I will need to use onComplete callback to loop music (create new Media object), I thought that using createBackgroundMedia() will be more elegant and efficient, but as I see now it's not appropriate for my task, background service is not what user expect from casual game

Comment: @Shai, there is an issue with regular play method, you can't play two sounds at the same time, play background music and some sound effect, say, typing or coins sound, it stops playback of first media in order to play second one, that's why I was searching for alternative and finally switched to createBackgroundMedia(), but may be I missing something, can you please advise ?

Comment: Create media and play should work in parallel. On which OS is it failing? Notice that media behaves very differently between devices/simulator etc.

Comment: This could be an issue,  can you file a test case with that issue?

Comment: sure @Shai, I will post this question as issue on GitHub