# MediaManager.addCompletionHandler doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, codenameone

I have another issue with `MediaManager`, I am trying to implement background music loop, and to achieve that I obviously use `addCompletionHandler`:

```
backgroundMedia = MediaManager.createBackgroundMedia(mediaPath);
MediaManager.addCompletionHandler(backgroundMedia, this);
backgroundMedia.setVolume(75);
backgroundMedia.play();
```

this code works in Simulator but doesn't work on the real Android device (6.0, 8.1)

Before that, I have tried to achieve the same with regular `MediaManager.createMedia` but as I mentioned in comments of my another question, it doesn't play two sounds in parallel, so either background music or sound effect will be played:

[Background music (MediaManager.createBackgroundMedia) causes crashes at app closing/opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53318556/background-music-mediamanager-createbackgroundmedia-causes-crashes-at-app-clos)

So at this moment, I see no way to play background music in a loop continuously in Codename One, maybe somebody has the workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

On platforms other than Android background media is a synonym to regular media playback. We need this special API only for Android. I'm not sure if completion handler is meant to work with background media as the app might stop running while background media is playing.

Comment: I see, but then how do I know when playback completed ? 
looks like I need to put some timer there and set it to the length of music, this is the only way I see

Comment: Yes. You will notice that background media is the only media type where a completion event isn't an option on creation...

Comment: true, but `MediaManager` itself has `addCompletionHandler`, so I thought that it will work, and it looked like the only chance to implement background music looping, because simultaneous play of two regular sounds using `MediaManager.createMedia` doesn't work on Android device also

Comment: timer also has its own pitfalls, it should be handled properly at app foreground/background transitions (`start()/stop()`), app crashes when switching to foreground, `IllegalStateException`, can't figure out why, I didn't think that background music will be so tricky to implement ...

Comment: Background music should be easy to implement, you are using background media playback which is a completely different thing designed for a completely different purpose (running when the app isn't). You should either wait until the bug with media playback is resolved or submit a pull request with the fix. The code is all in git and is all Java since this is Android

Comment: yes, conceptually it's very easy, I like how media playback is designed in CodenameOne, but as you mentioned, there are two bugs, you can't play two media files at the same time, first will stop to play, and background media playback cause crashes when you kill the app on Android 4, 5 and 6, also there is no completion callback for background media playback, so the only way I see is two figure out how to use it together with timer

Comment: Regarding fixing of bugs, that sounds easy for those who already "in the code", and not so easy for people who just getting familiar with Codename One :)

Comment: Only one of these bugs (the concurrent playback) should matter. The second thing isn't an issue. You can use Android Studio to debug this: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html it's not trivial but probably easier than the iOS equivalent.